# asp.net gridview / Devexpress Maintain Gridview Checkbox state after moving Page

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview, devexpress

As I need to Maintain Gridview Checkbox state after Navigating the Page in Gridview .

As I have try with DevExpress gridviewdatacheckcolumn ,As I have added check box template col in the same. but i am not able to Maintain the State of gridview. check box column after navigating through the Grid View Page.

So please guide me on the same.

```
 <dx:gridviewdatacheckcolumn caption="Presence" ShowInCustomizationForm="true"  visibleindex="9">
                 <DataItemTemplate>
                 <dxe:ASPxCheckBox runat="server" ValueUnchecked="true" ID="chk"></dxe:ASPxCheckBox>
                 </DataItemTemplate>

                 </dx:gridviewdatacheckcolumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean CheckBox State from Database (Checked/UnChecked State), or User Selection?

If it is user Selection, try enabling ViewState on the Gridview.